# Type error - is not a function

Tags: jquery

I have a combobox that on change console logs the value

```
jQuery( '#divid' ).on( 'change', function () {
     console.log( jQuery( '#divid option:selected' ).text());
}
```

This works fine, but I feel it is an unoptimised piece of code. I have have changed it to the code below

```
jQuery( '#divid' ).on( 'change', function () {
     console.log( jQuery( '#divid' ).children("option").is("selected").text());
}
```

However I get an error

> TypeError: jQuery(...).children(...).is(...).text is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: because you missed colon operator in selected as it should be :selected

Comment: `is("selected")` returns a boolean value so you can't call `text()` on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `is()` method returns a boolean, which does not have a `text()` method. To do what you require, you could use `filter()` with `:selected`:

```
jQuery('#divid').children("option").filter(":selected").text()
```

I would say however, that there is nothing wrong with your first example, and in my opinion is preferable due to being more readable.

Comment: Or `jQuery("#divid > option:selected").text()`